# Simple javascript html image game

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple game where image moves randomly and score increases when user clicks on it.

The first image displays before game is started, which when clicked calls the play() function in javascript, which hides that image and displays the image that is to be used for the game.

That is where my code is stuck, it does not call the function play(). I am new to javascript and html. Any help would be great!

Here is my code

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>Image click Game!</title> 
      <script>
         global var score = 0;
         global var left=400;
         global var top = 100;

         function play() {

            var game = document.getElementById('game');
            var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            var width = window.innerWidth;

            firstDiv.style = 'display : none';
            game.style='display : block';

            setInterval("move()", 1000);
        }

        function move() {
           var randomNumberX = Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;
           var randomNumberY = Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;

           left = left + randomNumberX;
           top = top+randomNumberY;

           var im = document.getElementById('image');
           im.style.left = left;
           im.style.top = top;
       }

       </script> 
    </head> 
 <body> 

    <div id ="firstDiv" style="display : block">
        <img src="pics/playgame.gif" width="108" height="106" onClick = "play()"/></a>
    </div>

        <div id="game" style="display : none">
            <p>"Score: " + score</p>
            <img id="image" src="pics/gameImage.gif"  onClick = "score++" style="position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100;"/></a>
        </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: First, install firebug and see if it shown any errors in javascript. This is how u debug your code

Comment: did you try to place an alert just before the code var game = document.getElementById('game'); ? are you getting that alert? also as Andrew said please check the console of the browser to see if there is any error

Comment: Thank You. I got that part to work.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as my browser, so do you think Chrome developer tools are enough for code validating..

Comment: what is the benefit of an alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of things wrong with your code:

1) Your `<img>` tags are ended with a stray, unneeded `</a>` tag.

2) In your `<img>` tag, you should change to `onClick = "play();"`

3) I don't believe javascript supports the `global` keyword in that way.

4) To change CSS style, try this:

```
firstDiv.style.display = 'none';
game.style.display = 'block';
```

5) You cannot display javascript variables in this fashion: `<p>"Score: " + score</p>`...not to mention there is no declared variable 'score' to begin with!

Keep working at it, you only get better with practice.

Comment: Thanks JL. made the changes. Had a question though.

Comment: How can I access the javascript variable in html to display the score?

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this

```
<script> 

var score = 0;
var left=400;
var top = 100;

function play() {
  var game = document.getElementById('game');
  var firstDiv = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  firstDiv.style.display='none';
  game.style.display='block';
  setInterval("move()", 1000);
```

}

```
function move() {
  var randomNumberX=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;
  var randomNumberY=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)-5;
  left= left+randomNumberX;
  top = top+randomNumberY;
  var im= document.getElementById('image');
  im.style.left=left;
  im.style.top=top;
```

}